# Programmatically create UITextField events

Tags: iphone, uitableview, event-handling, uitextfield

I some add textfields programmatically into a TableView when the rows are created. I am trying to subscribe to the TouchUpInside event of these textFields by doing this

```
UITextField *eTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 12, 145, 25)];
eTextField.delegate = self;
[eTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(showPicker)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

showPicker is an IBAction with no parameters.It never  gets fired. Is there something I else I need to do?

Is there something I'm missing? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to show a picker for the text field instead of keyboard, you should assign the picker picker view as the `inputView` of the text field.

But if you want to fire some method when user touches the text field, you should override the 
text field delegate method

> textFieldDidBeginEditing

and call resign first responder to avoid the keyboard, and then write your custom code or method calls.

Comment: I had created a separate view with a "done" button for the picker view and was animating the displaying and hiding. Your idea of using `inputView` seems simpler, but how do I get the InputView (now aPicker) to be dismissed ? Making it `hidden = YES` makes it disappear forever.

Comment: when the text field is not the first responder, the input view dismisses.. so just call 'resignFirstResponder' on the text field in your done button's action..

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't it be [eTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(showPicker**:**)
Also you are not assign a UIControlEvent.

So:

```
[eTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(showPicker)
```

Should probably be changed in to

```
[eTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(showPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

1.Override `textFieldDidEndEditing` in your `viewController.m` file.
See the  example code below:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField*) tf{
 //your piece of code (goNext?)  
}
```

2.Remove

```
[eTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(goNext) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEventEditingDidEnd];
```

from your code.