# tableView prototype cell with action button outside tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am getting started with mobile application development with Swift. I designed a form within a viewController using tableView prototype cells (not using UITableViewController and static cells as I require to place other controls within the view controller).

Every cell has a unique identifier and designed using story board. I have created a sub class for UITableViewCell and assigned the same to all the cells.

```
class VehicleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet var txtModel: UITextField!
//@IBOutlet weak var txtModel: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtODO: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtFuel1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtFuel2: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var lblDistanceUnit: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblFuel2Unit: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblFuel1Unit: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblMake: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblFuelType: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblCurrency: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}}
```

Here is my UIViewController that does the regular stuff:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,  UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

// Array of cell identifiers
let cellArray = ["CellMake", "CellModel", "CellODO", "CellFuelType", "CellFuel1", "CellFuel2", "CellCurrency"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellArray[indexPath.row]) as! VehicleTableViewCell
    if indexPath.row == 1
    {
        cell.txtModel.addTarget(self, action: "txtModelChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        println("Inside index row 1")
    }

    return cell        
}

@IBAction func txtModelChanged(sender: UITextField!)
{
    println("test")
}}
```

Here are couple of things I'm confused and unable to proceed.

1. I have added target for txtModel at cellForRowAtIndexPath and mapped it to function txtModelChanged on touchUpInside event. Simply it didn't trigger the function nor it didn't throw any error. Any guess on what might be the issue?
2. I'm try to get values of all the objects on click of "Done" button. How to traverse through the tableView to get all the values?
3. Is there any other better way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

**First**

> If you want to fire some method, when user touches your UITextField - you should override text field delegate method `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and call resign first responder to avoid the keyboard, and then write your custom code or method calls.

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4919134/2210926

In this particular question, it is not important whether you're using Swift or Obj-C.

**Second**

It's not an option, you have no guarantee that all your cell view will be alive at that moment. You need to store all that data somewhere, like in an array for example.

Answer (score 0):

For generic form designing, I found https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog very helpful. I have used it in one of my application. If you want to implement your own logic then I think this sample will help you to infer the information.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 280;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 10;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
return cell;
}
```